# useEffect not re-rendering when expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm learning React Hooks and having some difficulty getting a component to re-render using useEffect and how to pass an onClick function to a child component that also is contained in useEffect.

I'm creating child components from a map of the state array containing numbers 1 through 12. These child components have an onClick function that randomises the array.
The aim being that once a number is clicked, the order is reshuffled and the new order is displayed.

The below code works, but only after I included the number and setNumber to force the render. Without these, nothing re-renders even though the array does shuffle.

Why is it that including the `setNumber(number + 1)` forces the render, but without that, nothing happens?

Additionally I'm not sure how to have the `randomiseArray` function be inside useEffect, but still be able to pass it to a child component.

```
const [array, setArray] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12])
const [number, setNumber] = useState(1)

useEffect(() => {
        
       
    })

 const randomiseArray = () => {
        let list = array
        list = list.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
        setArray(list)
        console.log(array)        // Shows array is shuffling
        setNumber(number + 1)     // Only after I include this does the component re-render
    } 


const content = array.map((index, key) => {
    return <Card onClick={randomiseArray} key={key} number={index}/>
  })

  return (
    <div className="board">
        {content}
    </div>
  );
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why is your ``useEffect`` empty?

Comment: Please share your card component code. I think you should call the function of the card component to re-render

Comment: Make a copy of your array first. Sorting the array and setting state will not cause rerender cause it still refers to the same object. `let list = [...array]`

Comment: Don't think you need to put randomise inside your useEffect. useEffect is called after the render. Here you want to trigger a render with randomise.

Comment: No problem. Check if you can close this question then.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the `array` and do `sort`

Try this code

```
 const randomiseArray = () => {
    setArray([...array.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)]);
  };
```

or

```
 const randomiseArray = () => {
    const list = [...array.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)];
    setArray(list);
  };
```

Code Sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ko1vri